# @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on x.person references an unknown entity: y.Person - inheritance issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i've got a problem with my Hibernate Architecture:

I have a MappedSuperClass Person, and an Employee and a Customer.

```
--> Person.class
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
public class Person extends PersistentObject {

    @Column(name="TITLE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Title title;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String  fname       = null;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String  lname       = null;

--> Employee.class
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEE")
@Audited
public class Employee extends Person {

--> Customer.class
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_CUSTOMER")
@Audited
public class Customer extends Person {
```

This works well, but now to my Problem: I've extended 'Person' with an List of Items, eg Addresses/Contact Informations/etc, and use a Single Table for all Items of the same Type (all Addresses).

When adding the Address to Customer only, this is no problem:

```
--> Customer.java
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="customer")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Address> addresses = null;

--> Address.java
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_ADDRESSES")
@Audited
public class Address extends PersistentObject {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Customer customer;
```

Now i'd like to extend the addresses to the Employee also. I thought, that i could use the Supertype to hold the address, but this doesn't seem to work right:

```
--> Person.java
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="person")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Address> addresses = null;

--> Address.java
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_ADDRESSES")
@Audited
public class Address extends PersistentObject {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;
```

When running, i get the following error: `@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on at.test.Address.person references an unknown entity: at.test.Person`

Is there a possibility to have both entities use the same table for their addresses? IDs wont conflict, because Employee and Customer share the same sequence. Or should i design this problem in another way?

Thank you very much in advance and best regards!

Comment: hava a look at this blog http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-concrete-class-annotation-xml-mapping/.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link, I realized that the "one table per subclass" paradigm was what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Flo's link I realized that the correct paradigm to use for my problem was the "one table per subclass" one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare your Superclass as an @Entity instead of @MappedSuperClass and a single table inheritancet strategy, so you can reference it in your ManyToOne relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="P")
public abstract class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="customer")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Address> addresses = null;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@DiscriminatorValue("E")
public class Employee extends Person {

}

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class Customer extends Person {

}

@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_ADDRESSES")
@Audited
public class Address extends PersistentObject {
     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
     private Person person;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this first hint. But what if i want to add many different attributes to Customer/Employee? Where are these stored? In a common table? In my opinion it would be the best to keep Customer/Employee tables and add an Discriminator to the address. I tried this, but it doesn't work as expected. Nevertheless, thanks for the input!

Comment: I have a similar question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252541/generatedvalue-for-a-java-abstract-superclass-over-mysql

Answer (score 0):

On the Address class you have to set parameters insertable and updatable to false. It actually make sense, because if you do not do that. JPA allows you to create some "Person" (perhaps not mapped) object, assign it to address, then persist along with the address object. Try with the code below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="customer")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Address> addresses = null;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@DiscriminatorValue("E")
public class Employee extends Person {

//some fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class Customer extends Person {
    //some fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_ADDRESSES")
@Audited
public class Address extends PersistentObject {
     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
     private Person person;
}
```