# How to implement single table inheritance using an interface as superclass and annotations with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an interface, an abstract class that implements the interface and some concrete classes that extend the abstract class. This hirarchy describes jobs which
only differ in the implementation of one method. This are excerpts of my classes:

**Job**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "job_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public interface Job {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    long getId();

    void setId(final long id);

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "previous_job_id")
    Job getPreviousJob();

    void setPreviousJob(final Job previousJob);

    public abstract void start();

}
```

**AbstractJob**

```
public abstract class AbstractJob implements Job {

    private long id;

    private Job previousJob;

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Job getPreviousJob() {
        return previousJob;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPreviousJob(final Job previousJob) {
        this.previousJob = previousJob;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Job[id=" + id + ", previousJob=" + previousJob + "]";
    }

}
```

**HelloWorldJob**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@DiscriminatorValue("hello_world")
public class HelloWorldJob extends AbstractJob {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

}
```

When I try to run a simple program that stores a `HelloWorldJob` using a `JpaRepository`, I get the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:752)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: HelloWorldJob
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    ... 22 more
```

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html#inheritance-tableperclass) has an example on how to do this using xml-mapping, but not using annotations. How can I map this with annotations?

Comment: I never worked with interfaces when Hibernate mapping, but you could try to annotate your interface with `@MappedSuperclass` instead of `@Entity`.

Comment: Then I get the following exception: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on HelloWorldJob.previousJob references an unknown entity: Job`

Comment: What if you put both?

Comment: Another exception stating that either one or the other but not both can be used: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass: Job`.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18185218/1225328

Comment: you may need to set @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) above your abstract class

Comment: Yes I had to add `@Inheritance` but I also had to remove the interface. Now I have only the abstract class and the concrete classes.

Comment: the abstract class should have implements Persistable<Long>

Answer (score 0):

From [en.wikibooks.org](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Interfaces):

> If you have a public interface in JPA, you just need to map the implementation class and are fine for the most part. One issue is that you need to use the implementation class for queries, as **JPA does not know about the interface**. For JPQL the default alias is also the implementation class, but you could redefine this to be the public interface by setting the name of the Entity to be the public interface.

JPA annotations on interfaces are ignored by JPA.